# Cross-reference issues in officedown

Tags: r, cross-reference, officedown

I'm having a problem with the cross-reference in an officedown rdocx_document, so for the first figure, the reference is printed correctly, with `Figure \@ref(fig:fami)`, but for the second column , the code `Figure \@ref(fig:ivi_plot)` prints only the text "@ref(fig:ivi_plot)" in the document. Below part of my rmarkdown code.

Would anyone know why? I found it strange that this happened because the settings for the two figures are exactly the same.

The yaml:

```
---
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d/%B/%Y')`"
author: "Florestal Package"
title: "Inventário Florestal - Relatório Técnico"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: "template.docx"
    tables:
      caption:
        style: Table Caption
        pre: 'Tabela '
        sep: '. '
    plots:
      caption:
        style: Image Caption
        pre: 'Figura '
        sep: '. '
    page_margins:
      bottom: 1
      top: 1
      right: 0.3
      left: 0.2
      header: 0.5
      footer: 0.5
      gutter: 0

---
```

The setup:

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F, fig.cap = TRUE,tab.cap=T,warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, dpi = 300,fig.align = "center")
```

The first figure:

```
{r echo=F, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap="Quantidade de indivíduos por família botânica na área do inventário.", fig.id="fami",fig.width=7.5, fig.height=5,out.width="100%"}

fam_tree
```

The second figure:

```
{r echo=F, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap="Índice de Valor de Importância (%), em que: FR (%) = Frequência Relativa; DR (%) = Densidade Relativa; DoR (%) = Dominância Relativa.",fig.id="ivi_plot", fig.width=7.5, fig.height=5,out.width="100%"}

all$`Gráfico de IVI`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the underscore in your fig.id